# Calculate correct number of characters using Awk ggsub

Tags: awk, gsub, fasta

I'm trying to calculate the number of a specific character pattern in a sequence (fasta format). In my case I want to calculate how often the context "CC" is present in a sequence. The whole script is working fine, but I experienced one small problem.

For calculating the "CC" context I use the following part of my script:

```
CC=gsub(/CC/,"CC");
print CC
```

I experience a problem when I have a fasta sequence like this:

```
>name_sequence_1
CCCCC
```

In this case, the number of CC should be 4 (positions 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, and 4-5), but gsub gives me the number 2, because after substituting the first CC, it jumps to the 3rd C and so on.

Is there any way how I can fix that using gsub or is there another code I can use to calculate such contexts?

Thanks!

Comment: What would the output be for string `CCCACCCCC`?

Comment: I don't understand why the number of `CC` in `CCCCC` should be `5`, while `CC` in `CC` is `1`.

Comment: @JamesBrown it gives 3

Comment: @tshiono because the `second` and `third`  `C` should also count as `1` `CC` context etc.

Comment: Like this?: `echo CCCACCCCC| awk '{match($0,/C+/);print RLENGTH}'` Hmm, due to your previous comment I guess not.

Comment: @Anelisa why would the output for `CCCCC` be 5 instead of 4 since the pairs of `CC`s are at character positions 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, and 4-5?

Comment: @Annelisa why would the output for input of `CCCACCCCC` be 3 instead of 6? Please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements if the expected output you state is correct or fix your expected output if it's wrong.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes you are right - my bad! I changed it into 4 now. Sorry

Comment: @EdMorton the input `CCCACCCCC` should indeed give an output 6, but the script gives me 3 instead

Comment: Annelisa the question [@JamesBrown asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71966981/calculate-correct-number-of-characters-using-awk-ggsub#comment127167727_71966981) wasn't what the incorrect output of your script was as that's not useful to us, it was what the correct output would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MAY be what you're trying to do, assuming the expected output you stated is wrong:

```
$ echo 'CCCCC' |
    awk '{
        str = $0
        cnt = 0
        while ( sub(/CC/,"C",str) ) {
            cnt++
        }
        print cnt
    }'
4
```

```
$ echo 'CCCACCCCC' |
    awk '{
        str = $0
        cnt = 0
        while ( sub(/CC/,"C",str) ) {
            cnt++
        }
        print cnt
    }'
6
```

but here's a more robust general solution that'll work even when the target string isn't a repetition of 1 character and/or it contains regexp or backreference metachars:

```
$ echo 'CCCCC' |
    awk '{
        cnt = 0
        for ( i=1; i<length($0); i++ ) {
            cnt += ( substr($0,i,2) == "CC" )
        }
        print cnt
    }'
4
```

```
$ echo 'CCCACCCCC' |
    awk '{
        cnt = 0
        for ( i=1; i<length($0); i++ ) {
            cnt += ( substr($0,i,2) == "CC" )
        }
        print cnt
    }'
6
```